# Jquery: get link by class or selector

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, selector

I'm creating a list of images from a folder, and then I open them in a fancybox... so I have thumnails, big images, and a text link to full image.

```
<div id="download_image">
  <p><a href="images/download/folder/big/<?php echo $file;?>" class="fancybox"><img src="<?php echo $path;?><?php echo $file?>" /></a></p>
  <p><a href="images/download/folder/full/<?php echo $file;?>.zip" class="btn-download">DOWNLOAD</a></p>
</div>
```

Then I'm getting images path by jquery, for each image:

```
var download_image = jQuery('#download_image');
var images  = download_image.find('img');

download_images.each(function(){
    var img = jQuery(this);
    var img_source = img.attr('src');
```

Now I need to get the url of the "btn-download" link for each image... but I don't know which selector must I use! Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Use `$('.btn-download')` to select an element by class.

If you want to get the href attribute then simply use:

```
var href = $('.btn-download').attr('href');
```

To loop through each element use:

```
$('.btn-download').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    // do something with href
})
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a list of images... so I need to get the url related to current image. by using "var href = $('.btn-download').attr('href');" I always get the url of first image...

Comment: @user1292580 Okay so use $('.btn-download').each(). I will post

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('a[class=btn-download]').attr('href')
```

Comment: The `a[]` is not necessary unless 'btn-download' is used on elements other than a tags

Comment: @Ben Carey, that's right, but he didn't show the full code so may be there is another element other than `a` tag use the same class

Comment: yup, I agree. As he asked for the class selector I just assumed he wanted to select all elements with that class.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.btn-download').each(function() {
  console.log(this.href); // get the normalized `href` property; fastest solution
  console.log($(this).attr('href')); // get the exact `href` attribute value
});
```

Note that the answers advocating `$('.btn-download').attr('href')` are incorrect, as those would only return the `href` attribute value for the first element in the set.

Answer (score 1):

```
var download_image = jQuery('#download_image');

download_image.each(function() {
    var imgUrl = $(this).find('p > a > img').prop('src');
    var downloadUrl = $(this).find('p > a.btn-download').prop('href');
    // do something with the urls here.
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fYNph/)

The `each`-function is kind of redundant, because you should only have one element with a specific id. Listed here just in case you want to have more than one download image and button.

In your question you mention that you are getting the path for each image. I strongly advise you to make `download_image` a class if you have more than one `download_image` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#download_image').each(function(){
    var img_source = $('img', this).attr('src');
    var link_href = $('a.btn-download', this).attr('href');
});
```